# Is there any database uses lzma?

Tags: database-recommendation, compression

according to [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/evaluating-database-compression-methods/), lzma has a great performance on compression ratio. I think lzma database is a good choice if I don't care about compression speed, so is there any database that uses it?

Comment: Most people aren't concerned with the granular details of what compression algorithm their database system uses, as it makes little difference in reality. What's your actual goal?

Comment: @J.D. I want to find a database that focuses on small storage space (needs a high compression ratio). Maybe mysql with zstd?

Comment: Why? What size disk are you working with? How much data do you plan on having?

Answer (score -1):

Almost all DBMS support data compression.

MS SQL Server:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-ver16

DB2: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=overview-data-compression

Oracle: https://www.oracle.com/database/advanced-compression/

MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-compression-usage.html

SQLite: https://sqlite.org/com/cerod.html

And so on...

All of them are using some variation of compression algorithm from `z` family. With zlib - most popular.
Some of DBMSs allow to choose which algorithm to use. So if you particularly fond of lzma, you have to go to **your** database documentation, find does it support compression and if yes, how to change the compression algorithm.

Comment: "All of them are using some variation of compression algorithm from z family" -- not true.